# Understanding norm in Number Field Sieve

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

In the research paper **Factoring integers with the number field sieve** by : *J.P. Buhler, H.W. Lenstra, Jr., and Carl Pomerance*

https://openaccess.leidenuniv.nl/bitstream/handle/1887/2149/346?sequence=1

under **5. The algebraic sieve :** they have used norm mapping $N: K \rightarrow Q$ , where $K$ is a number field and $Q$ is the rational field.

Later they are claiming that norm of elements of the form  $a+b\alpha$ can be computed by  substituting $a, b$ in the homogeneous polynomial $(-Y)^{d}f(-X/Y)$ that is, if $a, b \in Z$ then

$N(a+b\alpha) = a^{d} -c_{d-1}a^{d-1}b+...+(-1)^{d}c_0b^{d}$

where $f = X^{d} +c_{d-1}X^{d-1}+...+c_0$

I'm not getting how norm is equal to this $N(a+b\alpha) = (-Y)^{d}f(-X/Y)$.
I'm new to this field. Please explain it as easy as possible.
 Thanks in advance.